# How to calculate the multiplication result in two different ways?

Tags: calculus

First I want to apologize for a possibly ambiguous title, but don't know how to expose clearly the problem through the title because the speech is much more structured. I'm working on a system that allows me to get the value form of a team, this system uses the following formula:
$$
\mathrm{form}=\frac{6\cdot g_1+5\cdot g_2+4\cdot g_3+3\cdot g_4+2\cdot g_5+g_6}{63}.
$$
Practically the variables used are $g$ comes to a maximum of $6$ because I'm going to evaluate the form factor in the last six games. So everything is right. Let me explain the meaning of each variable "$g$" with an example:

$g_1\to$ result match Team $A - B (1-1); g_1\;\text{value}\;\to 1$ (team $A$ won $1$ points)
$g_2\to$ result match Team $A - B (2-2); g_2\;\text{value}\;\to 1$ (team $A$ won $1$ points)
$g_3\to$ result match Team $A - B (2-1); g_3\;\text{value}\;\to 3$ (team $A$ won $3$ points)
$g_4\to$ result match Team $A - B (1-1); g_4\;\text{value}\;\to 1$ (team $A$ won $1$ points)
$g_5\to$ result match Team $A - B (3-1); g_5\;\text{value}\;\to 3$ (team $A$ won $3$ points)
$g_6\to$ result match Team $A - B (4-1); g_6\;\text{value}\;\to 3$ (team $A$ won $3$ points)

**The formula assumes so this aspect:**
$$
\mathrm{form}=\frac{6\cdot 1+5\cdot 1+4\cdot 3+3\cdot 1+2\cdot 3+3}{63}.
$$
Total result is: $0.55$

At this point I apply this passage: $0.55\cdot 100 \to 55$ is the form of the team $A$. I calculated the form factor of the $A$ team. This is a generic example of how you use the formula.

**My problem:** I know the total points data from variables $(g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4, g_5, g_6)$, but I can not apply them individually as I did before. I can only calculate the total in that case is $12$. I would then find a way to apply that formula, or to achieve the same result by knowing only the total variable "$g$".

How do I extricate myself from this problem?

Comment: Does that mean a tie is worth $1$ point and a victory is worth $3$ points? Are there also points for losses?

Comment: Exactly, losses assigned 0 points.

Comment: @Heisenberg Nice prof pic [check mine out] ;) nice nickname steal btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to exactly figure it  out with only that information. There are a couple different ways of getting a sum of $12$ and so there are several different possible answers for you form factor.

You are in a little luck though - there are only two ways to get to $12$ by adding six $0$s, $1$s, and $3$s together: $3+3+3+3+0+0$, or $3+3+3+1+1+1$. So you know either $A$ won four games, and lost two others, or $A$ won $3$ games and tied $3$ others.  However, this doesn't say anything about the order.

Hence the minimum form factor is 
$$\frac{6\times0+5\times0+4\times3+3\times3+2\times3+1\times3}{63}\approx 0.48$$
and the maximum form factor is
$$\frac{6\times3+5\times3+4\times3+3\times3+2\times0+1\times0}{63}\approx 0.86$$

If you happen to know that actually $A$ had $3$ victories and $3$ ties, then the situation is a bit better: the minimum would be
$$\frac{6\times1+5\times1+4\times1+3\times3+2\times3+1\times3}{63}\approx 0.52$$
while the maximum would be
$$\frac{6\times3+5\times3+4\times3+3\times1+2\times1+1\times1}{63}\approx 0.81$$

Comment: I don't care to calculate the maximum and minimum form. The main problem is that I currently can only know the total value of each "g", but I know every "g" as true, but don't know the order of each "g"; so here's what I want to find an algorithm capable of calc the exact result using only the total of "g".

Comment: This algorithm, however, must not take account of the order of "g" which instead is my formula posted at the top. As I said the problem is very complex.

Comment: @Heisenberg it's impossible to get the exact form without more information - because the current form admits several solutions.

Comment: My formula uses 6 matches (the last six games played). Starting from the second last raced here because I'm going to multiply (6 *g1 + 5*g2 and so on ...).
Now I know how many points the team has obtained by sum all "g" variables, but in the formula I exploit the value in the order of "g", that's why I want to find a formula that uses the total of "g" and get the same result of the previous formula.

Comment: @Heisenberg There isn't any formula which can find the result with just that information. The order matters too much.

Comment: This would have saved me a lot of work both programming speed, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Heisenberg If possible, you should implement the formula in the way you have it already

Comment: I can implement it, but as I said, will require a lot of time to evaluate each "g"

Comment: @Heisenberg Unfortunately, if you need to use this exact form of the equation, there isn't a way to avoid it